# I can't upload dll files by Filezilla

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, filezilla, windows-server, upload

For a few weeks, without having changed any configuration of the server or my computer, I cannot upload any file with a DLL extension to the server, Windows 2012.

The error is a timeOut, but only with DLL.

Comment: Security measure? Antivirus?

Comment: I have tried giving all permissions to a specific path, disabled antivirus, firewall (temporary) and nothing. I am looking for updates of the OS of the date, in case one carries a package that blocks these uploads

Comment: FileZilla will transfer anything, so it still looks like something on the server won't allow it.

Comment: Can you think of any specific settings to look at? In the iis no blocking information arrives.

I am observing, that on the third attempt, the file is uploaded, although filezilla is not informed about it.

Comment: Can't think of anything. You might test the server when booting in Safe Mode with Networking (if uploads will work in this mode), to see if this is a third-party product or Windows itself.

Comment: Tnahks. It's a Virtual Machine.... I tried it at the next days...

Comment: If you rename the DLL, will it upload? I agree with @harrymc "FileZilla will transfer anything, so it still looks like something on the server won't allow it". Are you certain that you didn't change anything on the server?

Comment: There might be no Error, actually. Since "_the File is uploaded, although FileZilla is not informed about it_", then what is happening might be exactly what the Error Message is saying: a Time-Out. Due to Network Congestions, somehow _FileZilla_ does not wait until the File finishes uploading itself. I doubt that it is happening only with Files with the `.DLL` Extension. Maybe it could help if you posted the _exact_ Error Message.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using an **app_offline.htm** file.

Put the app_offline.htm file in the application root folder and the application will go offline releasing the dll's on the server.

You can then push your dll's to the server.

Then remove the app_offline.htm file from the server to restart the app.

When present the app_offline.htm will be displayed so you can put some html in there to show that the site is down for maintenance.